# Ecommerce Tracking is Dropping Campaign Source

Tags: google-analytics

Out of hundreds of transactions tracked recently using GA Ecommerce tracking, they're all showing a traffic source of Direct, and none of them are showing google organic (or any other traffic sources) as contributing any revenue.

From some quick testing, it appears that the traffic source is dropped when the customer switches from http over to https in the checkout process.

Any good solutions for this?

UPDATE: It looks like this may have been being caused by a duplicate snippet with a difference in the placement of the setDomainName line in the snippet.  No longer seeing the traffic source being dropped in GA Debugger in the checkout step, going to wait a day and see whether data begins to show up properly in reports.

Comment: Are you using the default magento GA module? If so what version of magento do you have installed?

Comment: Yes, default GA module.  I'm on EE 1.12.0.2.  Do you not see this happen?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't dropping querystring when redirecting from `http://domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com`?

Comment: Don't think so.  I was on www.domain after arriving from google, and I saw the campaign source tracking going through just fine for several page views, it wasn't until the checkout that the traffic source was dropped.

Comment: I'm glad that this has come back up - I forgot to check back on this thread. This isn't correct behavior - I suspect something else is amiss. I checked stock Magento, stock GA module, HTTPS enabled, and no loss of campaign source was detected in GA.

Comment: Yep, I think I found it - see my update on the question.  Will report back shortly.  Thanks for looking into it so deeply!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had some a duplicate GA snippet hiding out that was causing this.  Traffic source should not get dropped when the customer goes from http to https in the normal course of usage.

Big shout out to my boys Fabian and Phil for the help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good and easy way to solve this problem:

## HTTPS EVERYWHERE

The customers data are worth to be protected and https is not anymore a performance problem with modern CPUs.

Comment: +1 Yes I was suspecting that might be the answer.  What happens though if someone is referred to the site from a non-https connection?  Does the referral get lost in that case?

Comment: good question. If you redirect him I think yes, because the JS is not executed and after the redirect it is gone. But I don'T have a solution at the moment.

Comment: I personally hate this idea. This has caching and 3rd-party javascript include impact.

Comment: What do you mean with caching? And Javascript should be no problem too, why should it? http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/01/15/https-performance-tuning/ and http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/01/28/top-7-myths-about-https/

Comment: 3rd parties don't always provide HTTPS - some I've encountered include Bazaarvoice, Bronto. Varnish doesn't handle https traffic.

Comment: But how do you handle it on your checkout if they don'T provide https?

Comment: I, frankly, would not recommend serving up everything over HTTPS. However, if you were to do that, you would simply need to implement the 301/302 redirect to the secure page via an Apache rewrite rule which maintained both the query string and URI.

Comment: `Varnish doesn't support HTTPs` shouldn't have any bearing on whether to use HTTPS or not. It isn't a web server or SSL terminator, so it is irrelevant that it won't support HTTPs, it doesn't need to. If you've got Varnish listening on port 80 and something else on 443 your machine is set up incorrectly.